Automate task on docker-compose down
Before each execution of docker-compose down, I would like to run a script that will download the MYSQL table from the container to my host computer. While the command:
docker cp app-db-1:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql /home/kwws2/App/db/php_docker_table.sql

works correctly, I am not able to automate it.
Can anyone tell me where to look for an answer to my challenge?

Not possible with on-board tools. See this github.com comment by the docker team.
